# website login automation in Perl?

Tags: perl

I am a beginner in Perl.I am thinking about making a script that automate the login process but I don't how to start? can I do this using [`LWP`](https://metacpan.org/pod/LWP) and [`HTML::TagParser`](https://metacpan.org/pod/HTML::TagParser) modules?

I tried to search data on this but I got confused. I am not getting the proper way to do this. Can anyone provide me some useful data or link on this?

Comment: [`WWW::Mechanize`](https://metacpan.org/pod/WWW::Mechanize`) to process a bunch of forms.  [`WWW::Mechanize::Firefox`](https://metacpan.org/pod/WWW::Mechanize::Firefox) if your forms require JavaScript.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would look at the [`Brownie`](https://metacpan.org/pod/Brownie) CPAN module, which is designed for exactly this.  It also integrates with Selenium so that you can drive an actual browser for websites that require local Javascript, etc.

It's a relatively young module, however; it may have bugs, and it certainly has some rough spots.  [`WWW::Mechanize`](https://metacpan.org/pod/WWW::Mechanize) is a well-tested module that has been around much longer, and has its own driver for Firefox that doesn't use Selenium. It is just perhaps a bit more complicated to set up and use than Brownie.